# Parsing an Excel file to the database using Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, excel

On my website in want to read a XLSX Data and send this to my DB.
I have already created an [upload with simple-excel.js](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) .

Now my excel data is in a 3d Array. I know how to import the data with PHP. But PHP can't communicate with JavaScript (JavaScript works on Client site and PHP on server).

My idea is to create an JSON request with JavaScript and call a URL implemented in PHP. Is that possible? Does anyone have a different idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have security concerns why deal with the XLSX file on the client? Rewrite the form so that it uploads the file directly to the server. You don't have to write any client side javascript this way. Once on the server then you can use a library like http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Very nice. Thank u very much!

Comment: Maybe u can help me further. i understand how phpexcel works. I can now open a excel data from my computer by his path. But how can i open an external excel. it needs to be uploadet?

Comment: Yep. The form should upload the file to the server first. Once you have it on the server point phpexcel to the uploaded file.